# php htaccess dynamic url redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, hyperlink

I have the following encoded url `http://test.com/me/test/u/0/~/%5E!0/X10EX1gdFQkVOjUyZDk2ZjZi`
and the last part of the string contained the actual page name to redirected.
I have a index file that decode the url to actual page.
Is any possible solution for redirect the actual url using the same enocoded URL via htaccess?

i wrote a hteacces that split the url in index.php

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php [NE,B,L]
```

http://test.com/me/test/u/0/~/%5E!0/X10EX1gdFQkVOjUyZDk2ZjZi converted to

http://test.com/me/test/login.php in index.php

I need to redirect the page to login.php and keep the encoded URL..

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Don't know with `htaccess` but you can do this with `PHP`.

Comment: Does this htaccess redirect correctly? i don´t have much experience with it but it seems to me that you loose track of the encoded part of the url...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to decode the string in the htaccess: no, that is not possible, if it is more complex than just reordering the characters.

What you could do is redirect it to the index.php, let the index decode it and redirect from there again using header(...).

But one question remains: why!?

Comment: M decoded the the url in index.php..but i want to redirect to that decoded page keeping the encoded url..for eg :http://test.com/me/test/u/0/~/%5E!0/X10EX1gdFQkVOjUyZDk2ZjZi converted to

http://test.com/me/test/login.php and redirect to login.php n keeping the encoded URL

Comment: ah, okay, since you didn´t use the R flag in the htaccess your url doesn´t change during that redirect, but it would if you use header i guess. the easiest way i could think of would be that index.php just INCLUDES the decoded url.